# Fastlane Boarding with two-factor authentication

Tags: ios, heroku, testflight, fastlane

I followed the "Getting Started" guide on the boarding github page, but I keep getting this error on my heroku page `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

The boarding page does say that the two-factor auth works and to go here: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/README.md#2-step-verification but I'm not sure how to add that cookie to my heroku site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Performat I just added another user to my itunes connect that has admin privileges and doesn't have 2FA and just used that user to log in in fastlane

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up doing the same... Suboptimal, but better than nothing! 

Answer (score 9):

Fastlane now (as of version [2.160.0](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.160.0)) supports [Apple's App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/). This avoids all the problems with 2FA session hacks. There are still a few fastlane actions that do not have full support but the majority do.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/app-store-connect-api/ explains how to start using an API key in fastlane.

In summary, here's what you need to do (these examples come straight from that documentation):

1. [Create an App Store Connect API Key](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/api)
2. From that same page, download the new key .p8 private key file and save it somewhere safe (WARNING: you can only download it once). Take note of the Key ID and the Issuer ID as you'll need them again shortly.
3. Either use the `app_store_connect_api_key` action to specify the new key in your `Fastfile`:

```rb
lane :release do
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "D383SF739",
    issuer_id: "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
    key_filepath: "./AuthKey_D383SF739.p8",
    duration: 1200, # optional
    in_house: false, # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
  )

  pilot(api_key: api_key)
end
```

Or, write the details to a JSON file:

```json
{
  "key_id": "D383SF739",
  "issuer_id": "6053b7fe-68a8-4acb-89be-165aa6465141",
  "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHknlhdlYdLu\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "duration": 1200, # optional
  "in_house": false, # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
}
```

and reference the JSON file either in your `Fastfile`:

```rb
lane :release do
  pilot( api_key_path: "fastlane/D383SF739.json" )
end
```

Or via the command line:

```
$ fastlane pilot distribute --api_key_path fastlane/D383SF739.json
```

Comment: This is not supported for Enterprise accounts :(

Answer (score 0):

Please follow https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#application-specific-passwords

> If you want to upload builds to App Store Connect (actions upload_to_app_store and deliver) or TestFlight (actions upload_to_testflight, pilot or testflight) from your CI machine, you need to generate an application specific password:

Note: The application-specific password will not work if your action usage does anything else than uploading the binary, e.g. updating any metadata like setting release notes or distributing to testers, etc.

This is what I set up 2FA with Fastlane when 2FA enabled recently.

- export FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD=<Your App Password>
- Used [upload_to_testflight](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/) in my lane without any additional settings. Fastlane will use the above variable for Authentication.

> All other actions interacting with Apple's APIs do NOT accept application-specific passwords.

This is where you need the cookie stored in Fastlane and used. I had to do for changelog updation through my CI/CD setup.

1. Unlocking the keychain to store my user password

   security unlock-keychain -p $SYSTEM_PASSWORD
2. Generating cookie redirected to a file (token.txt).

   bundle exec fastlane spaceauth -u ci-user@company.com >& token.txt
3. Extracted the Auth token to file 'session'

   awk -F"'" '$0=$2' token.txt > session
4. Set the FASTLANE_SESSION variable before running Fastlane lane, it reads the value from the 'session' file created above.

   export FASTLANE_SESSION='$(<session)'
5. Run Fastlane testflight lane as usual.

In the above, I used both methods and if you are only uploading the package to Testflight, you only need to set the FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD variable.

Comment: How does spaceauth actually work for you? It's asking me to input the sms-code.

Comment: You need SMS to generate the cookie the first time, later on, you will use that cookie during the Fastlane run

Comment: Actually, I solved it by switching to the app_store_connect_api :) No need to use 2FA

Comment: @Frexuz how did you generate Appstore Connect API, the button on App Store is disable, although I have Admin Access.

Comment: @NiibFouda actually I wasn't admin, but the admin was able to create one and give it to me. Sorry I wouldn't know why yours is disabled

Comment: @Frexuz thank's for your reply. I asked the Account owner to create one and make it accessible for the Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues trying to use `pilot/upload_to_testflight` along side `FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD`. It was always giving me error on the 2FA step. Turns out that in order for `pilot` to use that env variable 2 arguments **must** to be passed on, `apple_id` and `skip_waiting_for_build_processing`, otherwise normal username and password auth will be used.

Note that this only works only for upload, for any other interactions the recommended approach is to use api_key.