# VSTS Task Apple App Store asks for 2FA code, but Fastlane Session and App-Specific are set

Tags: ios, fastlane, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, fastlane-pilot

I have created an Apple App Store task, and created an Endpoint with username/passowrd/App-Specific password and Fastlane Session. My username has 2FA enabled (requirement for fastlane to upload the ipa)

[image]

When running the task I get the following:

[image]

As you can see it still asks for a 2FA code. It seems that the Fastlane Session is not being read. If I enter an invalid token in the Fastlane Session, I get the same result.

Do you know what could this be?

Comment: Based on the log, the session cookie has been expired, when did you generate this session? Try to generate a new session and try again. [Support for CI machines](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#support-for-ci-machines)

Comment: This session was created in my machine minutes before running this task, and the task runs in an agent. Do you know how can I inspect the environment variables in the release definition?

Comment: You can read environment variables as general environment variables, such as PS: `Write-Host $env:fastlaneSessionEnvVar`, Shell: `echo $fastlaneSessionEnvVar`, NodeJS: `console.log(process.env[fastlaneSessionEnvVar])`

Comment: Did you check if there is any unexpected line break inserted in the session when you copy and paste it?

Comment: Using Fastlane's new support for App Store Connect API no longer requires 2FA hoops for most scenarios; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416345/1836776

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the CI system you are using might be escaping the `\n` in the fastlane session cookie incorrectly. Instead of using the environment variable, try copying over the `~/.fastlane/spaceship/[email]/cookie` file from your main computer to your CI system