# Fastlane doesn't work for Apple id with two factor authentication on continuous integration working with Gitlab

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, fastlane

My appleid has two factor authentication turned on. For continuous integration we use Fastlane tool.

```
Available session is not valid any more. Continuing with normal login.
Two-factor Authentication (6 digits code) is enabled for account 'my.account@gmail.com'
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Using Fastlane's new support for App Store Connect API no longer requires 2FA hoops for most scenarios; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65416345/1836776

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. On yout machine when CI is running, go to the terminal and type the following command:

   ```
   fastlane spaceauth -u my.account@gmail.com
   ```
2. Then fastlane will ask you about the code: `Please enter 6 digits code:`. Get it from another trusted device and type it here.
3. You will receive **FASTLANE_SESSION** key. Just copy and paste it.
4. Login to your gitlab account that is used along with your CI and go to `Settings > CI/CD > Variables`. Then define `FASTLANE_SESSION` variable, type the value and save.
5. Run your job again.

Comment: for some reason this does not work for me. I get fastlane session, set it up as ENV var and it still asks me to do 2FA

Comment: 100%  correct answer, Save my time. thank you.

Comment: This is for generate new Session Key. In my case I need to generate key after every new build. It get expire every day.

Answer (score 0):

from fastlane 2.173.0 - just use SPACESHIP_SKIP_2FA_UPGRADE=1  https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.173.0

Answer (score 0):

The process should be easier with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#apple-app-store-integration) (March 2023), which comes with:

> ### Apple App Store integration
>
> From GitLab 15.10, you can configure and validate your projects with Apple App Store credentials.
> You can then use those credentials in CI/CD pipelines to automate releases to Test Flight and the App Store.
>
> The integration is designed to be able to work out of the box with [**fastlane**](http://fastlane.tools/), but can be used with other build tools as well
>
> [image: integration]
>
> To record your experiences with the App Store integration, see this [feedback issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/feedback/-/issues/10).
> And [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwzAWVgJeK8)
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/apple_app_store.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/readme/-/issues/36).